# VBA - Search and replace with increment number

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a macro that searches and replace the text that also adds an addition numbers in a specified column and counts all the cells that contain a specified string. For example:

**Original**

```
NC
NC
NC
NC
...
```

**New**

```
NC_001
NC_002
NC_003
NC_004
...
```

How should I perform this replacement?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's always important to tell people [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), including snippets of any failed attempts so that they can understand what avenues you have missed. It's important because it motivates people to answer and it's important because it makes it *easier* to give high quality, relevant answers. With the current state of the question, this hasn't been achieved. If you edit the question, it's possible that the question can be prevented from being closed and the quantity, quality and clarity of answers you get will improve as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your values are in ColA (from A2 down), then in B2 put:

`=A2 & "_" & RIGHT("000"  & COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2), 3)`

and fill down.